# How to localize DataTable column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

This is my datatable

```
public static DataTable GetTableForApproval()
{
    using (var connection = Utils.Database.GetConnection())
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [UserID], [Username], " +
           "[Email], [Role], [Date] FROM [Users] WHERE [Role] = @role",
            connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", "Waiting");
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("UserID", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Role", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Registration date", typeof(DateTime));

            if (reader != null)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    table.Rows.Add((int)reader["UserID"], 
                       (string)reader["Username"], (string)reader["Email"],
                       (string)reader["Role"], (DateTime)reader["Date"]);
                }
            }
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to localize the columns names. Can you tell me how can I do this? I localized my .aspx pages, but I don't know how to localize the text in .cs files.

Comment: Why do you want to localize the column names? You don't. You want to localize the text that displays to your users.

Comment: Because I want columns names to be written in language, that users can understand.

Comment: Can you tell me how to localize strings from database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the resx files added to your project, Visual Studio generates strongly typed classes allowing you to access them. For example if you add the `Messages.resx` to your project a `Messages` static class will be created:

```
table.Columns.Add(Messages.UserId, typeof(int));
```

where `UserId` is a string resource you added.

A better solution would be to localize the user interface and not the column names of the DataTable. Here's an example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  %>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("UserID", typeof(int));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(i);
            }
            grdTest.DataSource = table;
            grdTest.DataBind();
        }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" 
                    HeaderText="default value" 
                    meta:resourcekey="Grid" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There's a `GridView` on the page bound to a `DataTable` with a single column. Notice the `meta:resourcekey="Grid"` attribute on the BoundField. Now add the special App_LocalResources folder to your web application and inside it a resource file named `Default.aspx.resx` assuming the web page is called `Default.aspx`. Inside you could add the following string resource:

```
Grid.HeaderText  |  Some value
```

The default value of the `HeaderText` given in the markup will be replaced with the one in the resource file provided it is present.